# How do I load just the data from SQL Server 2005 backup into a 2008 R2 database?

Tags: sql-server

I created a 2008 native database and I have the structures in place but need to load data from a 2005 backup.

Answer (score 3):

Is your new structure different of the structure in SQL Server 2005? You may restore the backup entirely, there is no need to create first the structure and then load the data.

Answer (score 2):

Restore the 2005 backup as a different database, then use a tool like [Red-Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to copy the data. Once you're happy, drop the restored copy of the 2005 data.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a tool like Redgate's [SQL Virtual Restore](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-virtual-restore/) you can access the database inside the backup without restoring it, just mounting the backup as a real live db.

If not, after restoring it (it will work and will be upgraded as SQL 2008 db), if the structure of the tables is identical, then you can easily use Management Studio's Import and Export wizard to copy the data. You'll need just to point between the source and the destination of your copy operation and the wizard will build an SSIS package (can be saved and reused later) that will do everything for you.

In case the structure of the tables is not the same between the two databases, than you'll need to do your own custom scripts to do that (to map between tables..to cast necessary types).